# Is there a library for python which does writes unit tests automatacally?

Tags: python

Is there a library for **python** which writes unit tests automatically?

I just know, that **Haskell** has a library that automatically writes tests and I have seen a **Pycon** on this, but I cannot find it. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the library [Hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), inspired by the venerable and much-lauded [QuickCheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck) in Haskell. It doesn't write tests for you, but it will generate test cases in attempt to invalidate properties you specify about your program.